# Eclipse Import Dialog Box Not Showing Anything

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to import an existing project into Eclipse. The dialog box that opens when you click "Import" in the "File" drop down list has no options to import a project at all. The dialog box has no active buttons except for the "Cancel" button. Tried changing workspace etc. but this dialog box doesn't even show me the "Import existing project" option.

Using Eclipse Luna on Windows.

Help?!

Comment: Which Luna download?

Comment: Add screen shot. You can share here http://imgur.com

Comment: When I asked which download, I literally meant which file did you download.

Comment: I apologize for the super late reply. It magically started showing up after a recent windows update. No clue what happened :/